# WebStorm is showing YAML files as text documents

Tags: yaml, webstorm

After my baby run through all of my keyboard, WebStorm is showing all my `.yml` files as text documents and I can't find a way to return it back how it was.

[image]

[image]

How do I solve this?

Comment: 1) Ensure that YAML plugin is enabled. 2) `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types` -- make sure that file type for YAML files (top list) has `*.yml` pattern assigned (middle list).

Comment: That works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure that YAML plugin is enabled (at `Settings/Preferences | Plugins`)
2. If it's there, then check `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types` -- make sure that file type for YAML files has `*.yml` pattern assigned.

[image]

*(screenshot is from PhpStorm 2020.3 ... but it is the same in WebStorm)*

In case if you are still using 2020.2 or older version, it looks like this:

[image]